# Spanning sets and Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $v_1, \dots v_n$ spans V and $T \in L(V, W)$. Prove that the list $Tv_1, \dots , Tv_n$ spans rangeT.

I said that if $v \in V = a_1v_1 + \dots + a_nv_n$

then $T(a_1v_1 + \dots + a_nv_n) = a_1w_1 + \dots + a_nw_n$ but how do I show this spans W if I don't know that T is surjective? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y\in \operatorname{im}T$ so there's $x=x_1 v_1+\cdots+x_n v_n\in V$ such that

$$T(x)=T(x_1 v_1+\cdots+x_n v_n)=x_1T(v_1)+\cdots+x_n T(v_n)=y$$
hence we proved that
$$\operatorname{im}T\subset \operatorname{span}(T(v_1),\ldots, T(v_n))$$
and the other inclusion is clear hence the equality.

Comment: how can you assume the span of the image is equal to the entire range of T??

Comment: By double inclusion.

Comment: @Soaps you pick a generic element in range$T$, namely $y$, and show that this element is contained in the span of the $Tv_i$.